# Scanning radio syslogs in Android

Tags: android, logcat

I am trying to extract some information from Android (e.g. LAST_CALL_FAIL_CAUSE). Some of the information I found on Google suggests scanning the radio logs for this. However, I am not really sure how to scan these logs or how to pro grammatically access them. I searched for this on Google but couldnt find anything useful. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

`LAST_CALL_FAIL_CAUSE` belongs to the radio log, the meaning of the value defined by the vendor of modem. eg, `LAST_CALL_FAIL_CAUSE = 16` means call failed normally, `LAST_CALL_FAIL_CAUSE = 17` means call failed because busy line. So, you have to have the modem vendor codes to know the exact meaning.