# Get the last call fail cause with Android

Tags: android, call, disconnect

I am new to Android development and I'm trying some core telephony development. Can anyone tell me how I can get the last call fail cause (or cause code)? I have seen references to LAST_CALL_FAIL_CAUSE, but I don't know how to implement this?

Thanks

Comment: Not necessarily what you were hoping to get but this question has been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13915306/scanning-radio-syslogs-in-android